# Passport with one of the empty pages torn at the corner

Tags: passport-renewals

One of the empty pages in my passport has corner that is torn. I have the torn piece as well. I went to apply for a South African visa and was told that that makes the passport damaged and not usable. The problem is I travel to the US in the next three weeks. Is it considered "damaged by the US as well for a torn part of one of the empty pages in the passport? Do I need to apply for a new passport because of this? Please advise.Thank you

Comment: Your passport is damaged, get a new one. Some official may overlook it, some will reject it. Not worth the risk. Get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You have been denied a visa once already, because the passport is damaged.
Best not risk more problems. Renew the passport.